# Decompile APK BUT THE KEY FILE STILL ENCRYPT

Tags: javascript, android, encryption

I am decompiling a apk.

After the progress , I get the source code of the apk.

However , I found the apk's key file such as html's file or js's file are still encrypt.

Like this

[image]

What's the meaning of this picture?

Is't the hexadecimal?

But I found I can't transfer it with hexadecimal.

How can I get the source code of the api.js file?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the decryption key? If not, you aren't supposed to see the source of `api.js`.

Answer (score 0):

The picture is the content of the file.

Yeah, it is hexadecimal.

You cannot look in api.js files without the decryption key.